# Use of Differential Back-up possible for CRM 2011 to CRM 2016 Migration

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, upgrade, crm

Can a SQL Server differential back-up independently go through the upgrade/migration process? The idea is to take a snapshot/full backup through the upgrade process (very time consuming for a large database) and then minimize business down time by running a differential backup through the same process then back-up and restore the upgraded 2016 *differential* database to the "full" back up. The differential "upgrade" would be a small amount of data, take a short amount of time and minimize time between system cut-over.

Comment: Voting to move this to DBA SE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible because the underlying database structure has changes between these two versions and you can't upgrade directly from 2011 to 2016 version. It has to be done in stages i.e. 2011->2013->2015->2016.

In addition to that, there are several compatibility issues that you would come across. I would recommend you to setup a separate SQL instance and CRM server because this process could take months to fully mature.